# How to build go server locally?

Tags: go

please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to build a server locally using a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/mat/besticon/).

And This is my file structure..

[image: file Structure]

I tried to run `go build` in the root directory but it's throwing an error. Btw the Root directory has no `.go` files but has an go.mod

> Error:- no Go files in I:\besticon-master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must run the build command in the `besticon/iconserver` directory. That is where the server application package is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build it inside the iconserver folder. The Makefile gives some hints about how to build it.

Comment: This project is using modules, not GOPATH. The project location does not matter in module mode, and GOPATH is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your input I've removed that from the answer.